# Browser support for getElementsByTagNameNS

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, cross-browser

Which browsers/versions support `getElementsByTagNameNS()`, and to which extent? I can't seem to find a good reference.

[Edit] I am interested in a complete reference, but my immediate need is for namespaced xml returned from an AJAX call (which jQuery doesn't seem to handle btw).

Comment: Your edit makes it a different question. You should aim to use XPath on the response instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_XPath and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641853/ie-ajax-xpath and http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/04/04/xpath-in-javascript-part-3/ . Make sure to send your AJAX response with a XML content type and use the `responseXML` property to get the XML DOM.

Comment: I use responseXML. I am ok with using xpath, but your third reference says: "By default, Internet Explorer’s XPath engine doesn’t work with namespaces".

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Document_Object_Model%29)?

Comment: Interesting link, unfortunately when I followed the references I didn't get more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sitepoint says](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS#compatibilitysection) Firefox as of version 1.5, Safari as of version 3 and Opera as of version 9.

Firefox versions lower than 3.6 did a case insensitive search which as [corrected in version 3.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagNameNS#Notes).

[Microsoft claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975199%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to support it as of IE9. However, [according to Dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkiweff.php), this is only true for HTML documents. I'm not sure if you can't really trust Dottoro because selecting by namespace does not make sense for HTML documents anyway.
You should be able to use XPath if `getElementsByTagNameNS` is not supported. Wrappers are required, though, since IE does not support the standard API – see [Yaldex](http://www.yaldex.com/ajax-tutorial-4/BBL0029.html) and [NCZOnline](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/04/04/xpath-in-javascript-part-3/) for hints how to get IE to cooperate. Or ask Microsoft's support.

I would recommend to ensure XHTML documents have actually been served with a XML content type when you plan to use the function on the DOM of a web page.

Chromium 14 does also support the method (and honors namespaces in contrast to old Safari versions). Support might have been in long before, I just don't know the earliest Chrome/Chromium version with support.

It seems all browsers but not IE are supporting [DOM Level 3 XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/). Use XPath to replace calls to `getElementsByTagNameNS` if there are issues with it. See [NCZOnline](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/17/xpath-in-javascript-part-1/) for an introduction and notes on browser support.

Comment: Sitepoint and Dottoro, that's what I had so far (and agree with your comment). Would you have a link for Chrome/Safari?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but this might be useful to someone. You can just use plain old `getElementsByTagName` in IE. Instead of calling `node.getElementsByTagNameNS('someNamespace', 'someNodeName')`, call `node.getElementsByTagName('someNamespace:someNodeName')`.

Or use the following shim:

```
var getElementsByTagNameNS = function(node, ns, tagName) {
  if (node.getElementsByTagNameNS) {
      return node.getElementsByTagNameNS(ns, tagName);
  }

  return node.getElementsByTagName(ns + ':' + tagName);
};
```

And call it like this:

```
getElementsByTagNameNS(someNode, 'someNamespace', 'someNodeName');
```

Comment: Note that in the above example, `ns` should be the namespace **name** not the URI, but since writing this I've realised that Firefox actually only accepts the URI, so a better option might be to use `node.getElementsByTagName('namespacename:tagname')` throughout your code.

Comment: Another alternative is to use an asterisk wildcard in place of the URI (which might not be known).  So you might modify the shim with: return node.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', tagName.split(':').pop());    In practice this works well, but it's not a universal solution as it doesn't handle namespace conflict. Anyway, just wanted to toss this in case it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [this reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS)?

Specifically, [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS#compatibilitysection).

Comment: Yes, the reference is outdated