# Alternative to getElementsByTagNameNS when running in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, xml-namespaces

I am parsing a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" w:ocxPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:macrosPresent="no">
  <w:body>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>smpl tag txt</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Below code works fine in Chrome and IE11 but not in IE8 because getElementsByTagNameNS is not supported.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "smpl.xml", false);
xhttp.send();
xml = xhttp.responseXML;

x = xml.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml', 't');    
document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any alternative to getElementsByTagNameNS which handles namespaces in IE8?

Comment: Do you *seriously* still need to support IE8?  I'm so sorry for you, man :(

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15871220

Comment: Yes, I was reading a/m article but I don't understand how to apply it - getElementsByTagName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml:t") does't help.

Comment: Finally getElementsByTagName("w:t") works ok in IE8 only. For >IE8 and Chrome still need to use getElementsByTagNameNS. Thank you, Rocket Hazmat!